# I need help coding a simple script in Unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I need some a assistance with my bash shell which to me seems to be pretty simple. I want to be able extract all of the links of a given website and print them to standard output. I want to this do all through a script of my own. My goal is to have the command and have the website, where I will be extracting all of the links from, to be an argument. Here's what I have so far:

> cat > extract_links
>
> > curl $1 | grep

I dont have really much programming experience so sorry if this isn't much of a start. Is it necessary to use regular expressions? If anyone is willing to help, a code that is as simple as possible will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Matching links with grep is difficult, since the anchor tags can span multiple lines. If you're not much of a programmer, I suggest you use existing tools to do this instead of trying to script your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a one-liner:

```
grep 'https?://[\w/&=.?]+' $1
```

This will find all urls. If by "link" you really mean "anchor tags" that is a bit trickier, but doable. You haven't given any sample input or output so I can't tell what you want for sure.

You can get fancier with the regex. It depends on how they are embedded in your documents

Answer (score -1):

This is a lot easier in Python.

Just use `x = string.find('href="')`, and define string as `string[x:]`, and run `string.find('"')` and use that value to rip out the url(`print string[x:y]`).
Put that into a while loop and you should be good to go